# Xamarin Forms - Changing ImageView from Android Toolbar.axml dynamically

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

To implement a logo in the navigation bar of a Xamarin Forms app (for the Android case), I am using the below Toolbar.axml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/xlogo_small" 
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

But now I want to dynamically change xlogo_small.png according to a `boolean` value determined by a web service call right after application load. I would rather if I can access the toolbar.axml to edit the logo dynamically from the **Xamarin Forms Shared Project** as there is where all the logic resides. However, I have not found a way to do it in the Xamarin.Android project either. Any solutions for Xamarin Forms / Android cases?

Comment: How about a simple dependency service that calls a method in the android project? It would just get the current toolbar of the app and then change the src-property of the image view.

Comment: this was the first thing that came to mind, but it seems that the FindViewById method is not usable if not from the MainActivity.cs. I hoped for some assistance with finding the Toolbar either directly from Xamarin Forms or via a dependency service

Answer (score 0):

How do you apply the toolbar? I'm not sure how it's done tbh, but I know how to get the default one.

Create a NavigationPageRenderer in your android project.

Call this method in the "OnAttachedToWindow" override

```
private void GetToolbar()
{
    Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < ChildCount; i++)
    {
        var child = GetChildAt(i);
        toolbar = child as Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar;
        if (toolbar != null)
        {
            //Here toolbar is found.
            //You might loop through the toolbars children and find your ImageView
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you get the ChildCount?

Comment: `toolbar.ChildCount` :P ( You can do it the same way i did it in the "GetToolbar" method

Comment: does your first loop refer to iterating through a set of children of which one would be the toolbar we want? In which case, inside the if condition, I would need another loop that iterates through the toolbar.ChildCount? If so, what does the ChildCount in the first loop refer to?

Comment: Yes i mean this. The first childcount refers to the NavigationPageRenderer or more specificly to "ViewGroup" which it inherits from somewhere up higher in the hierachy. (mentioned in my answer)